# Keeps data in memory or load every time the view is loaded?

Tags: android, singleton, mvp

I am implementing MVP pattern which is using a Repository pattern to provide data. Now I have a doubt about the best way to manage the relationship between activities or fragments and data. My app needs a set of objects which can big, lets suppose a List. That objects should be showed in a Map fragment. I know I can use a Singleton or Application object and keep there the data. The other choice is just load the data every time a view which needs that data is loaded. 
Having the data in a Singleton is easy and fast, but in my case the amount of objects can be big. Also, there are the problems to test an app which is using Singletons.
On the other side loading data every time the view is loaded can convey to performance issues. 
Perhaps the best could to implement one intermediate solution like caching the data?

Will be great to listen your experiences guys. Regards,

Edit: I decided to avoid Singleton using the cache to hold data. Here are the methods I'm using to cache:

```
/**
 * generic caching methods
 * @param key
 * @param object
 * @throws IOException
 */
private static void writeObject(String key, Object object) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = TheAAApp.getApp().openFileOutput(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(object);
    oos.close();
    fos.close();
    saveCurrentTimeStamp();
}

private static Object readObject(String key) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fis = TheAAApp.getApp().openFileInput(key);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    Object object = ois.readObject();
    return object;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion here is that Presenter should have no idea where the data is coming from - it just asks the Repository for it and that decides whether to load it from an in-memory cache or from db/network.

```
public class Repository {

    private Cache cache;
    private Network network;

    public void getData(Callback<Data> callback) {

        if (cache.hasData()) {
            callback.next(cache.getData);
        }
        else {
           getDataFromNetwork(callback);
        }
    }

    private getDataFromNetwork(Callback<Data> callback) {

        //etc
        cache.putData(data);
        callback.next(data);
    }
}
```

The other advantage of this over using a singleton is where Android has killed your app due to inactivity/memory constraints.  If you were relying entirely on a singleton then this can end up being null.

You can also experiment with different caching options without having to change any of your Presenter/View code.

Comment: Hi Jahnold, thank for your advice, actually is what I did. I decided finally not using Singleton, replacing it with a cache. My app is big and we'll see if it is possible to avoid it completely. I edit my question to put those methods because perhaps they can be useful for other people.